# Creating the sub-directories inside the Amazon S3 buckets using script

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I found the script for creating the buckets in the amazon s3 and maintaining the files inside that bucket in the following link.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/

But i want to create the sub-directories in the amazon s3 buckets and have to maintain the files inside those directories.Can any one please tell me whether that is possible using the api. If possible, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, it should be easy. instead of giving

`$s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "jurgens-nettuts-tutorial", $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)`

just give

```
$folderName = 'xyz/abc/filename';  // path on s3 bucket.
```

`$s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName,"jurgens-nettuts-tutorial" ,$folderName ,S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ );`

define the directory in foldername

Comment: can we create dynamic sub directories ?? to upload images in dynamic directories ?